# Lack of detail in Hatcher's proof of characterisation of the HEP

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, continuity

In page 14 of Algebraic Topology, Hatcher sketches a proof for the fact that a pair $(X, A)$ has the HEP iff $(X\times \{0\})\cup (A\times I)$ is a retract of $X\times I$. However, the argument rests on the fact that the map $F\colon (X\times\{0\})\cup(A\times I)\to Y$ induced by the homotopy you are extending is continuous.

In the book, Hatcher doesn't give any proof for the continuity of this map, which, at least to me, is not obvious as $A$ is allowed to be a general subspace, and so I don't see an obvious way to apply, for example, the pasting lemma, as $A\times I$ is not closed in general as a subspace of $(X\times \{0\})\cup (A\times I)$. I've found a proof of the continuity in https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/General_Topology/Homotopy, but I can't find in the page where does this proof come from in order to cite it.

Does anyone know a less involved argument than the one presented in the link, or some source where this proof is more detailed that I may be able to cite?

Comment: Hatcher provides the missing details in his [online appendix](https://pi.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/AT/ATapp.pdf) on page 15.

Comment: Thanks you, @kobe